# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TabWidget.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-tabhost

> I am trying to implement Tabs using TabHost in my app but i am getting this null pointer exception. below i have the code. can anyone please help me.

```
final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    final TabHost.TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
    final TabHost.TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");


    // Set the Tab name and Activity
    // that will be opened when particular Tab will be selected

    tab1.setIndicator("Upcoming Matches").setContent(new Intent(this, ViewOtherExpense.class));
    tab2.setIndicator("Recent Matches").setContent(new Intent(this, viewExpenseTypes.class));

    /** Add the tabs  to the TabHost to display. */
    tabHost.addTab(tab1);
    tabHost.addTab(tab2);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3399FF")); //selected
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ADD6FF")); //unselected
    //To change the Tab color
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ADD6FF"));//unselected

            }
            tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3399FF")); // selected

        }


    });
```

Comment: Try calling  `tabHost.setup();` after initialization.

Answer (score 1):

> You have to call `setup()` before adding tabs if loading `TabHost` is using `findViewById()`.

So I suggest you to add `tabHost.setup();` after initialization and before calling `tabHost.addTab()` like here

```
final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
tabHost.setup();
```